# Issue using cpp_redis pub/sub with conditional variables

Tags: c++, redis

I have created two applications using cpp_redis; one using the publish and the other subscriber. I have wrapped the redis client into a class as I want the ability to change the comms in the future. The issue I am experiencing is the callback from my class is not working when using conditional variable. Using the redis-cli monitor I can see the event being publish but not received by the subscriber application. If I change the code to use an atomic variable and replace the conditional variable in the main loop and add *while(!atomic_var) to wait;*, the subscribe callback works.

```
class EventComms : public IEventComms
{
public:
    EventComms(cpp_redis::client &client, string channel);
    ~EventComms();
    void Publish(string uid);
    void Subscribe(TSubCallbackFunction callback);
private:
    string comms_channel;
    cpp_redis::client &redis_client;
    cpp_redis::subscriber sub;
};

void EventComms::Subscribe(TSubCallbackFunction callback) {
    sub.connect();
    sub.subscribe(comms_channel, 
            [&](const string& channel, const string& message){
        if (comms_channel == channel) {
            callback(message);
        }
    });
    sub.commit();
}
```

My publish code.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    cpp_redis::client client;
    client.connect();
    EventComms *comms = new EventComms(client, "/TEST");
    char c;
    while (1) {
        cout << "Waiting for commands " << endl;
        c = getchar();
        switch (c) {
            case 'p':
            {
                string uuid = generateUuidString();
                comms->Publish(uuid);
                break;
            }
            default:
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

My subscribe code.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    std::condition_variable cv;
    cpp_redis::client client;
    client.connect();
    EventComms comms(client, "/TEST");
        comms.Subscribe([&](string message) {
        event_id = message;
        cout << "rx message: " << message << endl;
        waitcv.notify_all();
    }
    );;
    cout << "started software" << endl;
    while(1) {
        std::mutex mutex;
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex);
        waitcv.wait(lock);
        cout << "Received data: " << event_id << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

not sure that  am not completely off here, but in 
https://cylix.github.io/cpp_redis/html/classcpp__redis_1_1subscriber.html#ab7feafca57399394e3a1a0d6daf52770

they say:
The cpp_redis::subscriber is meant to be used for PUB/SUB communication with the Redis server. Please do not use cpp_redis::client to subscribe to some Redis channels as:

- the behavior is undefined
- cpp_redis::client is not meant for that

hope this helps.
(I am still struggling with PUB/SUB myself, so I don't have a solution)